# design pattern common condition check

Tags: design-patterns, conditional-statements

I'm trying to figure out if there's a design pattern for checking common conditions.

So i want to design a configuration where a user can build its own condition.
Example for better understanding:

object     Fieldname  Condition  Value

customer   amount     >          2000
or
customer   contract   contains   life insurance

Is there any patterns that can describe such a system and/or helps on the common checking such a condition?

Thanks in advance.
Matthew

PS: if there's any missunderstanding from my question, let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of GoF book the closest one would be [Interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

[Composite specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern) could do the job.

However, concrete Specification implementations are specific to one object type, so you might either declare a base type with the relevant fields for the objects you want to check, or tweak the pattern using reflection for truly dynamic checking.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the Criteria pattern is the one you are looking for.